# Node.js, express variable weight

Tags: node.js, variables, express

I'd like to know the best way to declare variables in express.

Just a variable for my app

```
var app = express();

app.fs = require('fs');

app.WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
app.wss = new app.WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
})

app.mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.async = require('async');
```

or initialise a new var each time I need one

```
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
})

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var async = require('async');
```

I think the first method is better for the server but I fear to override express methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `app.get` and `app.set`:

```
var app = express();

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
})
app.set('wss', wss);
// later you can call `app.get('wss')`
```

Comment: yes but it require more from the server to decalrate a variable no ?

Comment: If you're talking about performance, the difference is negligible. `get` and `set` are nice ways of attaching data to your application without setting properties on the application object itself (and potentially overriding built-in properties).